# URL Masking in blazor to hide senstive information

Tags: asp.net, url, blazor, blazor-webassembly, masking

In blazor, I have URL which navigates me to bing maps based on provided latitude, longitude, Bing key. But I see my sensitive information in the maps address bar. So, I want to Mask the url without losing the functionality of the URL. How can I do that?

There are Paid api URL shortners which I dont want to use. Are there any methods with which I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: Doesn't MS have a maps service API?  You should be able to embed maps in your site instead of navigating offsite.